# How to stop auto expanding of Aurora's storage (volume)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

***UPDATE: 10-9-2019:*** After spending much time on trying to find a solution, I terminated the RDS instance and started a regular EC2 instance with Mysql. You're welcomed to keep browsing this question, I just won't be able to validate solutions since I'm no longer using Aurora.

I've been using AWS RDS instance (R5.large) with Aurora engine for the last few months.

I saw this related question however it did not help me to find a solution to this problem:
[Why is my "volume bytes used" always increasing on my Amazon Aurora cluster?](https://serverfault.com/questions/873699/why-is-my-volume-bytes-used-always-increasing-on-my-amazon-aurora-cluster)

I understand that this is the way Aurora works, but I couldn't find a solution relevant to my situation, as there is no option to limit the storage (volume) that will be used by the instance.

I've come to an understand that this thing wouldn't happen on mySQL@RDS or mySQL@EC2, exclusively for Aurora.

I'm looking for a resolution on this subject, and considering migrating to regular mySQL instance because of this problem.
If I were to create a new RDS instance with mySQL instead of Aurora than I can predefine the volume to use.

In the instance there is only one DB, and in that DB there is only one table.  each day I TRUNCATE (empty) the table, and insert about 200-500MB to it.

Even after disabling backups, the daily inserted data goes ON TOP of the data inserted until now, as if it was commutative storage used since instance was launched.

This resulted to reported of over 6000MB usage, while the real usage never exceeded 500MB.

Every month about 2GB of data is being added on top of the existing data. so in 5 years I will be paying for over 100GB of storage, even tho the real usage will never exceed 200-500MB.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(data_length)/1024/1024) AS data_in_mb, ROUND(SUM(index_length)/1024/1024) AS index_in_mb, ROUND(SUM(data_free)/1024/1024) AS free_in_mb FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES; 
+------------+-------------+------------+
| data_in_mb | index_in_mb | free_in_mb |
+------------+-------------+------------+
| 290        | 2           | 2210       |
+------------+-------------+------------+
```

[Reported Volume Bytes Used in AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE7jx.png)

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: What resolution are you looking for? The linked answer has evidence that Aurora is not interested in reclaiming free space that small.

Comment: Are you running with `innodb_file_per_table = ON`?

Comment: Does the system keep backups and count them toward your usage?

Comment: 1. I'm looking for a way to limit Aurora storage, or to make it relevant to the real usage. As I says in 5 years it will be 100GB and I'm looking for a way to avoid this outcome. 

2. I checked and innodb_file_per_table is ON. 

3. No, it used to backup and I thought that was the reason for the unreal volume usage, but even after disabling backups (and making sure all snapshots are deleted) the reported volume usage didn't change.