# Major difference in storage measured by Amazon Aurora vs Postgres

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds

When I query postgres for the size of all databases, I'm getting 430 GB.

```
select pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_database_size(d.datname) ))
from pg_catalog.pg_database d;

> 430 GB
```

However, Amazon Aurora is reporting "Volume Bytes Used" as 824GB.

[image]

This question has some tips for MySQL but I wonder why this would be the case for Postgres:
[Why is my "volume bytes used" always increasing on my Amazon Aurora cluster?](https://serverfault.com/questions/873699/why-is-my-volume-bytes-used-always-increasing-on-my-amazon-aurora-cluster)

Comment: I'm using Aurora for Postgres 9.6.19 - going to try updating and seeing if that fixes the issue: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-aurora-enables-dynamic-resizing-database-storage-space/

Comment: Possibly something to do with redundant disk storage across multiple AZs?